# GCM Downstream Message acknowledgement to App Server

Tags: http, google-cloud-messaging, message

Does HTTP API (Downstream messaging) in GCM support acknowledgement whether Android Client received notification or not?

Answer (score 0):

No. The farthest it can go is give info on how well your HTTP request went while the GCM server was processing it: [GCM responses](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#response).

You could use the [XMPP server](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs) instead.